# i keep getting the error undefined variable. where am i going wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i cant seem to find whats the problem im trying to create a simple ease scroll effect im using the jQuery pluging easing.js ans well as jquery-1.11.0.min.js

```
$(function(){
        //catch all clicks
        $("a").click(function(){
            // check if it has a #
            if(this.hash){
                // get rid of the # sign
                var hash = this.hash.substr(1);
                // get position ofd the links name
                var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
                var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;
                // scroll animate to postion
                $("body,html").animate({
                    scrollTop : toPosition
                },2000,"easeOutExpo");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

and even when i try it like this i still get the same error:

```
        $(function(){
        //catch all clicks
        $("a").click(function(){
            // check if it has a #
            if(this.hash){
                // get rid of the # sign
                var hash = this.hash.substr(1);
                // get position ofd the links name
                var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
                var $toPosition = $toElement.position().top;
                // scroll animate to postion
                $("body,html").animate({
                    scrollTop : toPosition
                },2000,"easeOutExpo");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Which variable is supposed to be `undefined`? Is the only difference between the two examples that you use `toPosition` in the first and `$toPosition` in the second?

Comment: the error kicks out on this line: var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;

Comment: this.hash ? what is that suppose to get?

Comment: So `$toElement.position()` returns `undefined`?

Comment: @Jermimbilal It's supposed to get the hashbang part of an url, which is also my guess why a variable is undefined, because the url in the href property didn't contain it.

Comment: @Jermimbilal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement#Properties: *"[hash] Is a DOMString representing the fragment identifier, including the leading hash mark ('#'), if any, in the referenced URL."*  If `this.hash` was `undefined`, then the `if` statement would not be executed and no error would be thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that

```
var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
```

doesn't match any element.

Then, `$toElement.position()` is `null`.

Therefore,

```
$toElement.position().top;
```

throws an error.

To fix it, you could try

```
var position = $("a[name="+hash+"]").position();
if(!toPosition) return false;
var topPosition = position.top;
```